# as3 Click thumbnail to tween large image

Tags: image, actionscript-3, event-handling, load, movieclip

I'm using Greensock's LoaderMax to parse an XML doc and load thumbnails and large images onto the stage - the large images are hidden off screen initially.

What I'd like to do is click on a thumbnail and have the large image tween into place, I have assigned the same name to the relevant thumbnail and image, ie 0 in thumbs corresponds to the 0 image

Thumbnails have been added to a movieclip named mc2, images are in a mc called bigDocWrap

Here's my attempt:

```
function callFull(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var clicked = [event.target.name]; 
    if (isUp == true) {
        // Do some stuff
    fadeOut.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, end);
        function end(event:TweenEvent) {
        // Some more stuff
                // Animate large image in
        mcDocIn = new Tween (clicked, "y", Strong.easeOut, clicked.y, -650, 1, true);
        }       
    }
}
```

This didn't work - undefined reference error

```
mcDocIn = new Tween (bigDocWrap.clicked, "y", Strong.easeOut, bigDocWrap.clicked.y, -650, 1, true);
```

Comment: You may want to look at the line `var clicked = [event.target.name];` What is that resolving to? Is it actually a display object? If not, then the first `Tween` wouldn't work because the target doesn't exist. If it is actually a display object, then the second `Tween` wouldn't work because you can't reference a child  of a parent (in this case `bigDocWrap`) in the way you are doing it.

Comment: When I trace the var it display the correct object name but I'm not sure what it actually resolves to - Flash isn't kicking out any errors , it just doesn't do anything :)

Comment: I believe that it's actually just resolving to a `String`. The square brackets around `event.target.name` aren't doing anything. You need to do something like `bigDocWrap[clicked]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing Name of object and not object to `new Tween()`. Use `event.currentTarget` or `event.target`, depends on your need.

I have updated your code like so:

```
function callFull(event:MouseEvent):void 
{

   if (isUp == true) {
    // Do some stuff
    fadeOut.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, end);
       function end(event:TweenEvent) {
         // Some more stuff
         // Animate large image in
         mcDocIn = new Tween (event.currentTarget, "y", Strong.easeOut, clicked.y, -650, 1, true);
       }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah that would have worked if I hadn't used Greensock LoaderMax to import the XML file! Chucks out this error
    `Type Coercion failed: cannot convert com.greensock.loading.display::ContentDisplay@39bc1241 to flash.display.MovieClip.
 at MethodInfo-312()`

Comment: See update. I have directly passed `event.currentTarget` to `new Tween(...)`;